# SVN post-commit hook doesn't open up GUI

Tags: .net, svn, post-commit

I've created a form application in .NET which will be used in the post-commit hook.
the problem is that the UI of the application is not shown.

What may be the problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

my UI should show Issue numbers of the developer. from there he should choose the Issue number that will be inserted to the log message. I've completed the script. But the UI is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but if you are using TortoiseSVN [this piece about issue tracker integration](http://tortoisesvn.net/issuetracker_integration) might help.

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware that the post-commit hook script is executed on the subversion server, right? It's not executed on the client side. As Sander states above, there shouldn't be any interaction. Usual things you do within a post-commit hook:

- Send email
- Trigger an automated build

Answer (score 0):

Subversion hook scripts are designed as scripts, they shouldn't show user interface, or require user interaction.

Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?